# How to correctly link wxWidget static libraries in Code::blocks?

Tags: mingw, codeblocks, wxwidgets, linker-errors, static-linking

I am getting multiple(160+) undefined reference to `XXXXXXXXXX' when compiling a wxwidget project, 
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW#undefined_reference

says

> your static libs MUST be given before shared libs.
>
> "-lwx_mswXXXXXX" and "XXXXXXXXXXX/libXXXXXX.a"

i have no shared libraries in this project.

i built the wxwidget 3.1.1 librarbies using this command:

```
mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -j4 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release UNICODE=1 SHARED=0
```

I am using mingw distro (nuwen ) gcc version 7.3.0 with codeblocks 17.02

i setup the project with the wxwidget wizard in codeblocks.
I've have tried the dummy source code before, its working when built with a shared library.

i linked all libraries in project>build Options>linker setting:
[image: Build options]

search directories are:
compiler: C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\mswu
linker: C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib
resource compiler : C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\mswu

here is the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Release in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib -o bin\Release\test.exe  obj\Release\testApp.o obj\Release\testMain.o obj\Release\resource.res -s -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -mthreads  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -lshlwapi -lversion -lwxmsw31u_richtext -lwxmsw31u_xrc -lwxmsw31u_aui -lwxmsw31u_media -lwxbase31u_net -lwxmsw31u_gl -lwxbase31u_xml -lwxmsw31u_adv -lwxmsw31u_html -lwxmsw31u_core -lwxbase31u -lwxpng -lwxjpeg -lwxtiff -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -lshlwapi -lversion -mwindows
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0xc1e1): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0xc205): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0xc266): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0xc7c1): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0xc874): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10459): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x104bd): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeBackgroundContentRect'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10520): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10c7a): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10cfe): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeBackgroundContentRect'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10d53): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10d6e): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeParentBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10da5): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x10dd2): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x117d7): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_window.o):window.cpp:(.text+0x118ba): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x8c0): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x8f0): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeMargins'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x930): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x946): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x3fd3): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x4008): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x402b): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeParentBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x405a): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x4089): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeMargins'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x40d7): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_anybutton.o):anybutton.cpp:(.text+0x663f): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x539): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeSysColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x571): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeSysColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x5b3): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeSysColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x6d5): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeSysColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x757): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x1ff7): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x2025): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeMargins'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x20ed): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemePartSize'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x2174): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeInt'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x2199): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeSysFont'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x22d1): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x2ef8): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x37a3): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x380e): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x38a5): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x3bc6): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x4768): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x477c): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x478b): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x47fa): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x4b7a): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x4d37): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_menuitem.o):menuitem.cpp:(.text+0x505e): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_statbox.o):statbox.cpp:(.text+0x2d60): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_statbox.o):statbox.cpp:(.text+0x2d91): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeFont'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_statbox.o):statbox.cpp:(.text+0x2db7): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_statbox.o):statbox.cpp:(.text+0x2ed2): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_statusbar.o):statusbar.cpp:(.text+0x1a10): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_statusbar.o):statusbar.cpp:(.text+0x1a3e): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeBackgroundContentRect'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_statusbar.o):statusbar.cpp:(.text+0x1a75): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_statusbar.o):statusbar.cpp:(.text+0x237d): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x4bd): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x4d6): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemePartDefined'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x4f8): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x53e): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemePartSize'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x567): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x60f): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x6b5): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x712): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeBackgroundContentRect'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x7c2): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x8c9): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x931): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x945): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemePartDefined'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x9a2): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemePartSize'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x9ef): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xa38): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xa81): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xabd): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemePartDefined'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xb14): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xb51): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeParentBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xbae): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xbf6): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xc91): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xcf6): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xd26): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemePartDefined'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xdb7): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xe01): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xe3b): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0xfd6): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1095): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x10ba): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x111d): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x11b6): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x11f6): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x12a4): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x12c9): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x132d): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1395): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x14bf): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x151e): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x17d2): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1848): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1963): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1a1b): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1bb6): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x1ca5): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x24d1): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x2630): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x266a): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x2693): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x26d9): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x273d): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x27b7): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x2823): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x2b27): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x2b81): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemePartDefined'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x2be1): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x33c8): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_uxtheme.o):uxtheme.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `__imp_IsAppThemed'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_uxtheme.o):uxtheme.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemeActive'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0xf3f): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1249): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1849): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1aa9): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1c01): undefined reference to `__imp_IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1c31): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeParentBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1c6d): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1cbd): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x1d85): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_combo.o):combo.cpp:(.text+0x22c9): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x1861): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x18c1): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeBackgroundExtent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x1918): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x1968): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x19cd): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x1e56): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x1e87): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeColor'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x1f78): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x2008): undefined reference to `__imp_GetCurrentThemeName'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x2294): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x30a5): undefined reference to `__imp_SetWindowTheme'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x6760): undefined reference to `__imp_OpenThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x67a0): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeBackgroundExtent'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x67c3): undefined reference to `__imp_DrawThemeBackground'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x67d1): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_msw_notebook.o):notebook.cpp:(.text+0x67eb): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseThemeData'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_access.o):access.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `CreateStdAccessibleObject'
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw31u_core.a(corelib_systhemectrl.o):systhemectrl.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `__imp_SetWindowTheme'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a wxWidgets project with the codeblocks wizard, the configuration options must match the options you used to build the wxWidgets libary.  Since you said you built with the options

```
UNICODE=1 SHARED=0
```

the options in the wizard should look like this:

[image]

Also the codeblocks wizard doesen't add 2 libraries needed for linking with wxWidgets 3.1.1 statically.  So you'll need to manually add libuxtheme.a and liboleacc.a like so:

[image]

(this is true as of 4/22/2018, but hopefully the wizard will be patched soon.)

Comment: it worked =) TY_VM, just added these 2 libraries you highlighted from MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib